# How to fetch all the profile changes by managed package

Tags: managed-package, permissions, metadata

I want to track and fetch all the metadata changes that occur in a profile when an installed package is added for users who have that profile.

I tried using the SetupAuditTrail object but it does not have the required data I'm looking for. I want the ability to fetch each and every change (ex: system permissions that the package automatically enabled, fields that it automatically enabled etc).

Is there any way to do this? I also plan to use this functionality outside of Salesforce.

Comment: There are many different ways that profiles may be updated by a managed package. One is by selecting "Install for All Users" or "Install for Specific Profiles". Essentially every **new** custom object and custom field added by the managed package install/upgrade are added to all/the selected profiles when using one of these options. Additionally, every **new** custom permission is added to those same profiles. If you install for admin only, these changes are only applied to the System Administrator profile.

Comment: Of course, if the managed package includes its own profiles, these are defined however the package dictates...

Comment: thanks for the reply, Phil. My question was related to how I can track/get to know how a particular package is changing an existing profile. Like for example, if I install a package for all users, it can enable certain features/permissions in ALL profiles. I want to track this.

Comment: I understand. As you said, this does not appear to be tracked in the way you want. My point was that the behaviour is determined by the option selected by the admin and that it is everything **new** in the package's namespace from the object schema and custom permissions.